# RubyMineでAnalysisComplieのエラー一覧の確認方法

Tags: ruby, rubymine

RubyMineでコード上にエラーがあると、Project上のエラーがあるソースを赤い下線で教えてくれます。

このエラーのソースコードと行番号を一覧で確認したいのですが、このような機能が無いかどうか、教えて頂けないでしょうか？

*Eclipseの問題ビューのような感じです

Comment: 「RubyMineでコード上にエラーがあると、Project上のエラーがあるソースを赤い下線で教えてくれます。」の具体例をスクリーンショットとして質問に追記してください。実際どんなエラーが出ているのかわからないと、回答も付きにくいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Eclipseの問題ビューのような感じです

たぶんEclipseの問題ビューに一番近い機能は、**Inspection**になると思います。

### 手順

**Inspection**を出すスマートな方法は他にもあるのかもしれませんが、以下の方法で出ました。

#### Project -> ProjectをProblemsに切り替える

追記：特に切り替える必要はありませんでした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 右クリックでInspect Code... を選択

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### Inspection scopeを選択する

プロジェクトのファイル量に比例しますが、
OKを押すとProblemsを見つけるまでかなり時間がかかりました。
なので、Custom scopeを自分なりに編集して、適切なフォルダ配下だけを対象にするなどの必要性があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 画面下部にInspectionが出現する

以上の操作で画面下部に該当ファイルの一覧が出現しました。
（出現したファイルはプロジェクトに関わるものなのでスクリーンショットには載せていません）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Problemsにもこの画面下部Inspectionと同じファイル一覧が出るのかと期待しましたが、出ませんでした....(正確には出る時と出ない時があった) StackOverflowはご自身でも回答ができたり、他の人の回答を改良できたりするので、もっと良い方法があれば、ご自身で回答されてもよいかもしれません。

Comment: まさに、確認したかった項目そのものです。
助かりました、ご回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: @TakenoriHirao よかったです。解決した場合は、回答にチェックをお願いします。